# Actualizar parametros React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

Estoy intentando hacer un `Lector de Barra` con un componente de `expo` la cual funciona bastante bien, el problema surge cuando quiero pasar los `datos capturado` a otro componente, no llega ni se actualiza.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
import Codigo from './Codigo';

export default function App() {
 const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
 const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
 var barra='...';
 useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
   const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
   setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
  })();
 }, []);
 const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
  setScanned(true);
  barra = { tipo: type, codigo: data };
  alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
  console.log(barra);
 };

 if (hasPermission === null) {
  return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
 }
 if (hasPermission === false) {
  return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
 }

 return (
  <View
   style={{
    flex: 2,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
   }}>
   <Codigo data={barra}/>
   <BarCodeScanner
    onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
   />
   {scanned && (
    <Button title={'Tap to Scan Again'} onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />
   )}
  </View>
 );
}
```

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Codigo extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      connected: false,
      barra: this.props.data
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.data !== this.props.barra) {
      console.log(nextProps.data);
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View><Text>{this.props.data}</Text></View>
    )
  }
}
```

En la primera parte, captura y asigna normal, pero en el segundo componente llega el valor inicial que le di `...`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te sucede es fácil de entender cuando entiendes el funcionamiento de los componentes como funciones y los hooks de react.

Básicamente lo que te está sucediendo es que cada vez que ejecutas el método `handleBarCodeScanned` este setea el valor de `barra` al objeto que creas, pero también hace algo interesante antes de eso, y es llamar a la función `setScanned` esta función es de un hook, la que maneja el estado en estas funciones, por lo que causará que tu componente se vuelva a renderizar con los valores actualizados, es decir, todo tu componente `App` volverá a hacer render y solo recuperará los valores que se encuentran en un estado, para este caso, los valores que hayas guardado con `useState`. Por lo que al volver a ejecutarse el componente, se encuentra con esta línea `var barra = '...'` y es por eso que tu valor no cambia.

Te recomiendo que intentes usar un `useState` para eso.

```
...
const [ barra, setBarra ] = useState('...');
...

// reemplaza tu método
const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
  setScanned(true);
  setBarra({ tipo: type, codigo: data });
  alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
};
```

Cualquier pregunta o inquietud no olvides comentar la respuesta y te ayudaré a resolverla